# Why is my currency format not working properly?

Tags: c#, xaml, decimal, viewmodel, currency

Within the following control I have attached as a data context a view model with some default values:

[image]

This is the class which I am using as the view model:

```
public class ContentViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged {
    /*Some variables omitted.*/
    private decimal _RoundPrice = 5.00M;

    /*Some properties omitted.*/
    public string Price { get { return string.Format( "{0:C}", this.RoundPrice ); } }
    public decimal RoundPrice {
        get { return this._RoundPrice; }
        set {
            this._RoundPrice = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged( "Price" );
        }
    }

    private void OnPropertyChanged( string Property ) {
        if ( this.PropertyChanged != null )
            this.PropertyChanged( this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs( Property ) );
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

In order to avoid having to implement a converter I've opted to just use a property to convert the underlying value for the count and for the price. I want to display the price like $5.00 but the format is omitting the currency symbol for some reason.

I've tried many methods to make the currency display with the dollar sign, all of which have failed to properly display the currency as it should be.

My frustrations not withstanding, is there some reason for this to not be displaying the dollar symbol in design time? Will this work in Run Time, or am I just hosed?

### EDIT 1

The manner of the binding of the value in question to the display medium has been requested :

The datacontext is bound as such :

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <local:TriviaContentViewModel/>
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

And the control which is supposed to display the price is bound as such:

```
<Components:WPFGLabel Text="{Binding RoundPrice}" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" TextAlignment="Left"/>
```

Comment: do you have other currencies also to be displayed or you just have to play with $ ? and how did you binded in xaml file? that matter s alot

Comment: The only currency symbol about which I care is a dollar sign ($).

Comment: Okay; and also, regarding the binding, see edit:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try specifying US culture in your binding like this

```
< TextBlock Text="{Binding Value, StringFormat=C, ConverterCulture=en-US}"/>
```

Comment: I love you bro... Wow; that's... I hate myself... seriously what the... Thank you.

Comment: no problem @Will that why I was asking how did you binded it in xaml. LUCK

Comment: So all the trying to string format on the property in the world was worthless; is it even necessary to use that property? hmmm I bet not; a quick experiment will tell...

Comment: Oh; also; i was binding to the wrong property /headdesk

Comment: for value yes, for currency no.